# Facebook app for review

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I've been working on an app on Android Studio, which requires me to go to pages of restaurants or clubs and get the events they are hosting.

Because i don't have public content access i have been using pages i am administrator of, but now i want to move on. So the app review for Public Content Access requires me to show them how i am using that data.

- Am i suppose to just show examples where i am using the data from the pages i am administrator off?
- Also i have never gone above the development stage of pretty much anything, so if i need to send them the entire app so they can test it, how would i do that ?

So far i only have a project on Android Studio and thats it.

EDIT:

- Also how can they get my app?
- Do i need to upload it or can they get it thorough the package name somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this :

> Also how can they get my app? Do i need to upload it or can they get
>   it thorough the package name somehow ?

Have you tested your app on your phone or emulator? If you have then Android Studio would have created an apk of your app.
You can find your apk where you have saved your project.

```
Project_Name > app > build > outputs > apk
```

You'll find an apk file which you can mail them.
They can download the apk and install that in their phones to test your app.

Just ask them to Check "Enable Unknown Sources" in `Settings > Security` before downloading the apk in mobile.